# Select some objects from a list of objects based on list of one field

Tags: java, object, arraylist, filter, java-8

I have an arraylist of objects which has a field "name" and I have a list of names. I have to select all the objects which consist of any of the name from the list. How can I achieve this in java most efficiently. Any code snippet will be highly appreciated.

Example:

Let the class name be `A`

A consists of fields such as  id, name, subject etc.

So let's assume I have a list
 `List<A> objectsA` 
whose length let's say is 10. In this list, the name field consists of various names for eg alpha, beta, gama, delta etc etc.

So suppose I have a second list

```
List<String> namesList = List.of("alpha","beta");
```

So I want to select only those objects from objectsA list whose name fields consist of the names from namesList i.e. I want to select only those objects whose name fields consists of "alpha" or "beta".

Comment: English is a **terrible** way to write Java code. Post some code. Show us something. Because I want to help you. But I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Okay sorry let me add some code

Comment: @ElliottFrisch have a look now.

Comment: thanks @gouessej for editing question and making it more readable. I'll make sure to ask in a better way from next time ....

Comment: You're welcome. You seem to be a beginner on StackOverflow, we have to give you some time to learn.

Comment: By the way, `List.of` is available since Java 9: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final ArrayList<MyNamedObject> namedObjectList = ...;
final List<String> nameList = ...;
```

Use

```
namedObjectList.stream()
   .filter((final MyNamedObject o) -> nameList.stream().anyMatch((final String name) -> Objects.equals(name, o.getName())))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If there are some duplicate values in the name list, either keep the list but use `.distinct()`:

```
namedObjectList.stream()
    .filter((final MyNamedObject o) -> nameList.stream().distinct().anyMatch((final String name) -> Objects.equals(name, o.getName())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or create a `Set`:

```
final Set<String> nameSet = nameList.stream()
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
namedObjectList.stream()
    .filter((final MyNamedObject o) -> nameSet.stream().anyMatch((final String name) -> Objects.equals(name, o.getName())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If `nameList` or `nameSet` can contain `null`, use `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`. If neither `name` nor `o.getName()` can be `null`, replace `Objects.equals(name, o.getName())` by `name.equals(o.getName())`.

Comment: thanks. I was looking for this, by the way what is time complexity of this code?

Comment: I don't know but I don't see how to suggest something more efficient in your case.

Comment: If you're sure that there is no null values, you can simplify a very little bit my example.

Comment: okay. I think as @Alberto Sinigaglia using set can be more efficient

Comment: There can be null values @gouessej

Comment: If `o.getName()` can return `null`, it will be enough. If `nameList` can contain null values, just add `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`.

Comment: Yes, you can use a `Set` to store names but I didn't want to modify your prerequisites. Anyway, if you use a set, my example will go on working, you can use any subtype of `Collection`.

Comment: You can use `.distinct()` on the stream obtained from the name list too but it can be less efficient than storing names into a set once for all.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `List` of names, then it's probably convenient to transform it to a `Set` so that you can easily check if it contains a name or not:

```
final Set<String> names = new HashSet<>(namesList);
List<Person> people = ...;
List<Person> result = people.stream()
   .filter(p -> names.contains(p.getName()))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can avoid using the `Set` and just use the `namesList`, because there is a `List.contains` method, however it would be fairly inefficient

Comment: You expect a list, rather use `Collectors.toList()`.

Comment: @gouessej I don't understand

Comment: You fixed it several minutes ago, you replaced `Collectors.toString()` by `Collectors.toList()`, it's ok now.

Comment: @gouessej oh ok, yes sorry, it was a typo